# Specify valgrind options to R package on Travis CI

Tags: r, unit-testing, travis-ci, r-package

I am trying to build an R package with c++ code on Travis CI and checking it with valgrind by running `R CMD check` with the `--use-valgrind` option. In the [R extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-valgrind) it says to either provide a `~/.valgrindrc` file with the required options or set them in the environment variable `VALGRIND_OPTS` but I haven't been able to figure out either of these.

I have created a demo repo [here](https://github.com/jolars/valgrindtestr) that includes a Rcpp function which valgrind ought to respond to.

My `.travis.yml` setup looks like this:

```
language: r
sudo: false
cache: packages

r_check_args: '--use-valgrind'

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - valgrind
```

I have a `.valgrindrc` file with the following,

```
--leak-check=full
--track-origins=yes
```

, and have tried to put it in `./inst/` and the root directory but none of that has worked. Does anybody know how to set these options properly?

*Edit: [here](https://travis-ci.org/jolars/valgrindtestr#L1259) is a link to the latest travis build.*

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with Rcpp right now. 2) You "just" have a Travis question. 3) I continue to use the previous Travis setup in [a fork I maintain](http://eddelbuettel.github.io/r-travis/) for *exactly* that reason: ability to script and access Travis anyway I want.  You could do that too. 4) You probably need `.valgrindrc` in `$HOME`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel you're right, I dropped the rcpp tag. Thank you for the suggestion. I don't know how to put the file there but I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.defopts), the file `./.valgrindrc` (so in the current working directory, is only read if the file `~/.valgrindrc` does not exist, and the environment variable `$VALGRIND_OPTS` is not set.

Not sure what is the case, but you might want to do the following:

```
before_install:
  - "head ~/.valgrindrc || echo '~/.valgrindrc does not exist'"
  - echo VALGRIND_OPTS: $VALGRIND_OPTS
  - cat ./valgrindrc >> ~/.valgrindrc
```

The first two are there for diagnostic purposes. The last one might fix the issue (it appends your configuration to the global configuration). If it would not work, you will likely have some more insight in what is at play.

Comment: Thank you. This lead me in the right direction. However, I figured out an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by @joepd works but I discovered a (perhaps) leaner solution in simply setting environment variables.

```
env:
  - VALGRIND_OPTS='--leak-check=full --track-origins=yes'
```

Note that valgrind still advises us to set `--leak-check=full` for some unknown reason, which is what brought me to look fro another solution in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following script to customise valgrind checks, and to flag what kind of output should cause a travis failure. Just make some kind of `valgrind-script.R` to load and test package functionality, then put both that and the following in the `tests` folder. (`valgrind` also needs to be installed with `.travis.yml`.)

```
vg_check <- function ()
{
    vg <- system2 (command = 'R',
                   args = c ('-d "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full"',
                             '-f valgrind-script.R'),
                   stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)

    lost <- NULL
    types <- c ("definitely lost", "indirectly lost", "possibly lost")
    for (ty in types)
    {
        lost_type <- which (grepl (ty, vg))
        n <- regmatches(vg [lost_type], gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", vg [lost_type]))
        lost <- c (lost, as.numeric (n [[1]] [2:3]))
    }
    if (any (lost > 0))
        stop ("valgrind memory leaks detected!")

    if (attr (vg, "status") != 0)
        stop ("valgrind error")
}

if (identical (Sys.getenv ("TRAVIS"), "true"))
{
    vg_check ()
}
```

This uses `memcheck`, but you can customise it to you use valgrind tool you like, and to translate any kind of output into a travis failure.